# Application-side join ORM for Node?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, orm, microservices, loopback

To start: I've tried Loopback. Loopback is nice but does not allow for relations across multiple REST data services, but rather makes a call to the initial data service and passes query parameters that ask it to perform the joined query.

Before I go reinventing the wheel and writing a massive wrapper around Loopback's loopback-rest-connector, I need to find out if there are any existing libraries or frameworks that already tackle this. My extensive Googling has turned up nothing so far.

In a true microservice environment, there is a service per database.

http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html

From this article:

> Implementing queries that join data that is now in multiple databases
>   is challenging. There are various solutions:
>
> - Application-side joins - the application performs the join rather than
>     the database. For example, a service (or the API gateway) could
>     retrieve a customer and their orders by first retrieving the customer
>     from the customer service and then querying the order service to
>     return the customer’s most recent orders.
> - Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) - maintain one or more
>     materialized views that contain data from multiple services. The views
>     are kept by services that subscribe to events that each services
>     publishes when it updates its data. For example, the online store
>     could implement a query that finds customers in a particular region
>     and their recent orders by maintaining a view that joins customers and
>     orders. The view is updated by a service that subscribes to customer
>     and order events.

EXAMPLE:

I have 2 data microservices:

GET /pets - Returns an object like

```
{
   "name":"ugly",
   "type":"dog",
   "owner":"chris"
}
```

and on a completely different microservice....

GET /owners/{OWNER_NAME} - Returns the owner info

```
 {
    "owner":"chris",
    "address":"under a bridge",
    "phone":"123-456-7890"
 }
```

And I have an API-level microservice that is going to call these two data services. This is the microservice that I will be applying this at.

I'd like to be able to establish a model for Pet such that, when I query pet, upon a successful response from GET /pets, it will "join" with owners (send a GET /owners/{OWNERS_NAME} for all responses), and to the user, simply return a list of pets that includes their owner's data.

So GET /pets (maybe something like Pets.find()) would return

```
{
  "name":"ugly",
  "type":"dog",
  "owner": "chris",
  "address": "under a bridge",
  "phone": "123-456-7890"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying any model/domain logic on your API-gateway is bad decision, and considered as bad practice. API Gateway should only do your systems's CAS (with relying onto Auth service which holds the logic), And convert incoming external requests into inner system requests (different headers/ requester payload data) and proxy formatted requests to services for any other work, recieves them, cares about encapsulating errors, and presents every response in proper external form.

Another point, if there is alot of joins between two models required for application core flow (validation/scoping etc) then perhaps you should reconsider to which Business Domain your models/services are bound. If it's same BD perhaps they should be together. Priciples of Domain-Driven-Design helped me to understand where real boundaries between micro-services are.

If you work with loopback (like we are and face same problem we faced - that loopback have no proper join implementation) you can have separate Report/Combined data service, which is only one who can access to all the service databases and does it only for READ purposes - i.e. queries. Provide it with separately set-up read-only wide access to the db - instead of having only one datasource being set up (single database) it should be able to read from all the databases which are in scope of this query-join db user.

Such service should able to generate proper joins with expected output schema from configuration json - like loopback models (thats what I did in same case). Once abstraction is done it's pretty simple to build/add any equery with any complex joins. It's clean, and it's easy to reason about. Also, it's DBA friendly. For me such approach worked well so far.

Comment: Hey Slavik! Thanks for the response. You bring up a lot of good points.

Our system is quite large and complex, so we will actually have a number (4) API Gateways, and many of the queries to be performed (and the relationships) will be used frequently by all 4 API Gateways.

I'm definitely taking into consideration the Report/Combined data service, though I want to be very frugal with which API Gateway functions I allow to use it, as it don't want it to be used for many queries (as it breaks the database-per-service pattern championed by Microservices).

Comment: (cont.) As it stands, I was planning on writing my own wrapper around Loopback that would allow me to handle automatic joins, but only to (essentially) save us the trouble of having to write the same exact joins in every damn API gateway business logic function.

Based on your feedback, I'm also going to attempt an audit of our current monolith DB to see which tables are most often joined together, in an attempt to inform the DDD you mentioned.

Comment: (cont.) This is part of a massive overhaul of an existing monolith .NET system. We also currently have a monolith SQL Server DB with a ridiculous number of tables.

We are trying to piece-by-piece transition to a true microservices-based environment, leveraging a (primarily) MEAN-stack informed design (with DynamoDB in place of Mongo because of AWS). Eventually we will probably end up with data stores that are a mixture of PostgreSQL and DynamoDB.

Comment: Perhpas in your case (if you use mixed data storage) the better solution is to do joins programatically (by adding layer you menntioned). In our case it was bit simplier because each micro-service used own database from same MySQL server, and that allow the combined query service to do database-level joins (which are preferable for many reasons).

Comment: (cont) as about of API Gateway, it should consume data and aggregate it from one, 'reciever' service through shared inter-service communication protocol, and not do data fetching the by it's own . If there alot of data joins requeired, perhaps, as I said before, it's better to delegate this task to dedicated service.